# THREE.js Border and overlay - Material Shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

With `THREE.js`, is it possible to give a sphere a material shader that will make it look something like this?  (The effect I'm looking for is the border, glow, and the streak going across the red.)

[image]

If so, can I get any help with finding good documentation/tutorials on material shaders?
Right now the material I'm using has a phong base phong shader, but it's not the effect I'm looking to achieve.

```
var protonMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xC31818,
    emissive: 0xBE2323,
    shininess: 0,
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});
```

Sorry I don't have much code, I don't know where to start for these shaders!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a combination of multiple materials to achieve that.

Have you already checked this [example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html)?

Comment: I've seen that example - I was thinking about extracting the glow effect from it.  I guess the main issue for me is the border and color line.  Hopefully bringing them all together will be easy.

Comment: Does the line depend by the camera point of view? Or you can split your sphere anywhere? Because if it's like that, you could just assign two different materials to the sphere and the line problem is solved

Comment: Yes it does, since the camera moves around and there is multiple spheres close to each other.